# SSRS having multiple dataset Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a Dataset1 which has all records.

I have Dataset2 and Dataset3 for Dropdown filteration.

Dataset1 has a query as follows : `select * from vw_shoppinghistory where storename =@storename and city = @city`

Dataset2  has a query as follows : `Select Distinct StoreName from vw_shoppinghistory`

Dataset3 has a query as follows : `Select distinct city from vw_shoppinghistory where storename = @storename`

On selecting store and then the city should pull the records.

I am facing an error as

" **When report contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope** "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing a field in a dataset on a control that doesn't count as a data region (data regions being things like charts, tables, lists, etc).  Most commonly you'll see this on textboxes.

To fix this, you need to do 2 things:

1. Use an aggregate expression.  You can't reference a field outside of a data region without performing aggregation.  You can use functions like SUM, FIRST, MIN, MAX, etc.
2. Specify a dataset when referencing a field.  For example, your code that's causing this error is going to look something like this:

   =Sum(Fields!city.Value)

What you'll need to do is specify the dataset the field comes from, like:

```
=Sum(Fields!City.Value, "Dataset1")
```

Comment: Thanks, i realized that. on any function, i have to mention which Dataset is mapped to the values. That would solve this problem. I fixed it. Thank you

Comment: Great!  FYI - in data regions, like in tables, you can get away with not specifying a dataset - in which case, SSRS will default you to the datas of the parent data region.